# DNS: Domain to subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, domains

I'm looking to get my mydomain.com and *.mydomain.com redirected to sub.domain.com only using DNS if at all possible. This is all the same domain.

So that:

- `www.domain.com         -> sub.mydomain.com`
- `mydomain.com           -> sub.mydomain.com`
- `anything.mydomain.com  -> sub.mydomain.com`

Comment: You can use a CNAME for `anything.mydomain.com` and `www.domain.com`, but not for the root domain. You will need a webserver to issue a 30x redirect for that.

Comment: DNS does not perform redirects. You will need to get an HTTP-aware server involved to do this.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks, how would I set it so that *.mydomain.com redirected? Would I just put *. in the name field?

Comment: Well there's the DNS `DNAME` record but I'm not sure how that would fly for `example.com` being "dnamed" down to `sub.example.com`

Comment: Would this be easier to be done with a htaccess file?

Comment: Point \*.mydomain.com to a webserver (A and/or AAAA records) using wildcard DNS records. Configure webserver to serve mydomain.com as main website and anything else (*.mydomain.com) as 30x redirect to scheme://mydomain.com (Apache can do this, using ServerAlias *.mydomain.com. Nginx can probably do it as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wildcard entry on the delegated name server for mydomain.com allows all FQDN's to resolve using the same A record.  A blank (or @ character) allows the domain itself to resolve to the IP.  Multiple A records to a single IP is allowed.

i.e.

```
mydomain.com.   300 IN A 10.1.2.3
*.mydomain.com. 300 IN A 10.1.2.3
```

Is all that would be needed.  No CNAMEs required.

Comment: This way one will get duplicate content issues, since all domains will be serving the same content. 301 redirect is the correct way to handle these.